# Dúvida com Time asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um `timer` que estou testando e o mesmo me retorna um erro:

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Resposta não está disponível neste contexto.

```
private static System.Timers.Timer timer;

protected void btnGerarArquivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 60;
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Teste);
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

public void Teste(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Response.Write("teste");
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("erro " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apos os ajustes ficou desta forma, mais não atualiza a tela:

```
     System.Threading.Timer tTime;

        protected void btnGerarArquivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tTime = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(Teste), null, 15000, 6000);
        }



        public void Teste(object sender)
        {
            horaCriacaoPagina.Text = "Hora atualizada : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
```

Comment: Tem que ter mais detalhes do erro, jovem. Provavelmente a exception não diz só isso.

Comment: @jbueno, eu tenho apenas o conteúdo apresentado, adicionei um try catch, veja se ajuda

Comment: Você precisa pegar o conteúdo da `InnerException`. Adicionar um try-catch só vai piorar as coisas, ao invés de ter a exception inteira ele vai retornar apenas a mensagem da primeira exceção, isso é péssimo. A propósito, por que você coloca seu código como `lang-html`? Isso é C#, o realce sintaxe fica prejudicado se você usar o comentário com `lang-html`.

Comment: @jbueno, eu adicionei a imagem, eu usei o lang-html, porque para mim é mais prático para ajustar o código.

Comment: Seu projeto é Web?

Comment: sim, é web agradeço a ajuda

Comment: E você esta querendo gerar um arquivo?

Comment: na verdade eu quero chama um procedimento com um intervalo de tempo, fiz este exemplo para tentar descobri o porque do erro.

Comment: acho legal você editar e tirar esses Response.Write, fica meio confuso

Comment: fiz um ajuste na pergunta, estou usando o System.Threading.Timer tTime; mais não atualiza o resultado na tela

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema é que seu projeto é Web e você esta tentando usar uma classe do Timer que não tem suporte para isso `private static System.Timers.Timer timer`;
quando deveria usar `System.Web.UI.Timer`.

O seu erro esta exatamente quando você tenta usar o Response, se você usar um this.Response, vera que existem vários erros na sua classe e um deles é.

> 'this.Response' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'

Lembre-se de que a biblioteca de classes do .NET Framework inclui quatro classes chamadas Timer, cada um do que oferece funcionalidade diferente:

- [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) **(Este tópico)**: dispara um evento em intervalos regulares. A classe destina para uso como um servidor com base em ou componente de serviço em um ambiente multithreaded; **ele não tem nenhuma interface do usuário e não é visível em tempo de execução**.
- System.Threading.Timer: executa um método de retorno de chamada única
  em um pool de threads em intervalos regulares. O método de retorno de
  chamada é definido quando o temporizador é instanciado e não pode ser
  alterado. Como o System.Timers.Timer classe, essa classe é destinada
  para uso como um componente baseado em servidor ou serviço em um
  ambiente multithreaded; ele não tem nenhuma interface do usuário e
  não é visível em tempo de execução.
- [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx): um componente do Windows Forms que
  dispara um evento em intervalos regulares. O componente não tem
  nenhuma interface do usuário e é projetado para uso em um ambiente de
  thread único.
- [System.Web.UI.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.timer(v=vs.110).aspx): um componente do ASP.NET que executa postbacks
  de página da web assíncrona ou síncrona em intervalos regulares.

Comment: fiz um ajuste na pergunta, estou usando o System.Threading.Timer tTime; mais não atualiza o resultado na tela